# Google Programmable Search Engine : Mobile pages not showing up

Tags: mobile, search-engine

Using Google Programmable Search Engine, I am trying to set up a search engine for the mobile version of a website.

I already put in place a search engine for the desktop version and it is working smoothly.

The engine for the mobile version is not.

Test have been done on a smartphone of course.

Site to explore : m.domain-name.com/* returns no result

Desktop version has canonical links. Redirection script is taking users to mobile version if needed.

Mobile version (m.domain-name.com) is showing well on main Google search engine.

Site to explore : *.domain-name.com/* returns desktop version pages. However when I click on a link in the results, redirection is not operating and I get the desktop page on a smartphone even if the page is reloaded, the script is not working. First time something like that is happening. Redirection script has always been reliable and is widely used online.

At this stage I am not using the API but only the control panel of the programmable search engine.

I submitted a dedicated sitemap with only mobile urls to the console. Hasn't changed anything.

So basically, one way or another, there is no mobile pages showing on a smartphone which is a bit of a problem !

Please note that website has about 800 pages. I know that responsive is the way to go these days but well 800 pages most of them with their own kind of codes it's a hell of a work to convert to responsive.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you very much for your help.